# how to use CSOM and search API to query a document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, csom

Below is my code to search for a keyword

```
using ( ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext ( new Uri ( "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/records/" ) ) )
{
    clientContext.Credentials = Credentials;
    KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery ( clientContext );
    keywordQuery.QueryText = "SharePoint";
    keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = false;

    // additional properties for keywordQuery which limit the results to particulat document library

    SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor ( clientContext );
    ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery ( keywordQuery );
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery ( );

    ResultTable resultTable = results.Value.FirstOrDefault ( );

}
```

I could barely find any working examples over the internet which restricts the results to only one particular document library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think if two easy ways to do it.

1. [Create a result source](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/11/04/how-to-configure-the-search-results-web-part-to-use-a-new-result-source-in-sharepoint-2013/): Configure the below query to result source

> {searchTerms} (ListID:{library guid here} AND
>   ContentClass:STS_ListItem )

Now set the KeyWordQuery to use the result source.

```
keywordQuery.SourceId="id of result source";
```

2.
 Just add the result source query directly into the query text.

> keywordQuery.QueryText="(ListID:{library guid here} AND
>   ContentClass:STS_ListItem ) SharePoint";

Comment: I quickly tried the second way and it works. I will try to test the first way when I have some time. Meanwhile I am marking this as the answer. Thanks.