# How to check if SharePoint URL exists?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, csom, url, azure-ad

Let's say we have the following SharePoint working URL:

```
https://mywebsite.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/Test.aspx
```

The following code works for determining if the URL works or not unless the user is authenticated with Azure AD access token

```
var request = NetHelper.CreateWebRequest(url,
                    allowAutoRedirect: true,
                    method: WebRequestMethods.Http.Head);
......
// Authentication
......
bool exists = false;
using (var response = request.GetResponseWithRetry())
{
    if (response != null)
    {
        exists = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
}
```

This method works when we have the `CookieContainer` (username/password authentication) for authenticating. However, as per [How to get cookies after obtaining Azure AD access token to SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/248732/how-to-get-cookies-after-obtaining-azure-ad-access-token-to-sharepoint-online/248735) it's not possible to make `WebRequest` work when Azure AD authentication is being used and we apply `HttpRequestHeader.Authorization` header.

I tried to use CSOM library:

```
var csomFile = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl);
context.Load(csomFile, f => f.Exists);
context.ExecuteQueryWithRetry();
bool exists = csomFile != null && csomFile.Exists;
```

However, this kind of code works only for actual files (I guess). It always returns `False` for the URL `https://mywebsite.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/Test.aspx`.

So, my question is - Is there a way to determine if the URL exists using CSOM library, assuming we already have the authenticated `ClientContext` object (which can use either `CookieContainer` or `HttpRequestHeader.Authorization` header).